# Python tornado autoreload not working when configured in a module

Tags: python, module, tornado, autoreload

I'm trying to figure out why Python Tornado autoreload feature does not work when configured and started inside a module. The following module contains a `MyTornadoApp` class that configures and starts autoreload if the proper option is set:

```py
import os
import tornado.autoreload
import tornado.web

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello from index handler!")

class MyTornadoApp:
    """Setup my custom tornado app with default settings"""

    # default tornado settings
    default_settings = dict(
        debug=False,
        autoreload=True,
        compress_response=True,
        port=8080,
    )

    default_handlers = [
        (r"/", IndexHandler),
    ]

    def __init__(self, user_settings):
        self.options = {**self.default_settings, **user_settings}

        if self.options['autoreload'] == True:
            self._autoreload_config()

        self.tornado = tornado.web.Application(self.default_handlers,
                                               **self.options)

    def _autoreload_config(self):
        """Setup autoreload for tornado"""
        print("Setting up autoreload for tornado...")
        # autoreload (exclusive) monitor file
        monitoring_file = os.path.abspath('autoreload')
        if not os.path.isfile(monitoring_file):
            with open(monitoring_file, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                f.write('Do NOT delete. Monitoring changes in this file!')
        tornado.autoreload.watch(monitoring_file)
        tornado.autoreload.start()
```

The main python script below then creates the tornado app but, unfortunately, `autoreload` only works if `start` is called (again, according to the Tornado emitted warning message). Any ideias why is this happening? Is it a feature or a bug? What am I missing? TIA.

```py
import asyncio
import tornado.web
from tornadoapp import MyTornadoApp

async def main():
    ################################################################
    #   Why do I need this in order to autoreload work properly???
    ################################################################
    if app.options['autoreload'] == True:
        tornado.autoreload.start()

    app.tornado.listen(app.options['port'])
    print(f"Tornado is listening on port {app.options['port']}")

    await asyncio.Event().wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_settings = dict(
        debug=False,
        autoreload=True,
    )
    app = MyTornadoApp(my_settings)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Please note the warning message: `tornado.autoreload started more than once in the same process`. But if we remove the `tornado.autoreload.start()` line from the `main()` function then autoreload will not be triggered if we change the monitoring file (or any other watched files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate quirk/flaw of `asyncio.run`: it will silently discard any event loop that already existed in the thread and create a new one to run the main function. Since Tornado initializes autoreload when the Application is constructed, that means it uses the wrong event loop when you construct it outside of `main`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete()` instead of `asyncio.run()`. This should work the way you expect, but this usage is deprecated and will be removed in some future version of python.
2. Continue to use `asyncio.run()`, but do *everything* (including construction of the Application) inside the main function. This is the recommended pattern for the future.

Comment: I used the second option. That worked for me. Thanks